# tryCatch in R execute in case of error

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

Is it possible to execute certain commands in case of error when using tryCatch in R ? I am using the code below but it does not execute X = alternative_value

```
tryCatch(
{
  X = certain_function_that_sometimes_returns_error      
},
error=function(e) {
  X = alternative_value
})
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assign your `tryCatch` directly to `x`

```r
foo <- function() stop("hello")  ## initiate an error using `stop()`
bar <- function() 'world'
    
x <- tryCatch( 
  {
    foo()
  },
  error = function(e) {
    bar()
  }
)
    
x
# [1] "world"
```