# Skip Line if Error Occurs within Function in R

Tags: r, try-catch

I am currently trying to solve a bug but believe the data I am working with may be too complex and cause errors that shouldn't normally occur. I've written a function, and was hoping to add a `try` or `tryCatch` statement to skip the error if it occurs. I currently have:

```
library(glmnet)
foo <- function(data, ols_ps = TRUE, index) {
  # index is the bootstrap sample index
  x <- data[index, -1]
  y <- data[index, 1]
  ridge <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0)
  ## The intercept estimate should be dropped.
  weights <- as.numeric(coef(ridge, s = ridge$lambda.min))[-1]
  # alpha=1, lasso
  alasso <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1,
                      penalty.factor = 1 / abs(weights))
  # Select nonzero coefficients
  coef <- as.vector(coef(alasso, s = alasso$lambda.min, 
                         exact = TRUE, x = x, y = y,
                         penalty.factor = 1 / abs(weights)))[-1]
  if (ols_ps == TRUE) {
    coef_nonzero <- coef != 0
    new_x <- tryCatch(x[, coef_nonzero, drop = FALSE], 
                      error=function(e) NA)
    if (!any(is.na(new_x)) & ncol(new_x) > 0) {
      ls.obj <- lm(y ~ new_x)
      ls_coef <- (ls.obj$coefficients)[-1]
      coef[coef_nonzero] <- ls_coef
    } else {
      coef <- coef
    }
  } else {
    coef <- coef
  }
  return(coef)
}
```

which normally works and works on most datasets. I think the error may be coming from a complex dataset. Is it possible to skip OLS if I get the below error?

> "Error in x[, coef_nonzero, drop = FALSE] : \n  (subscript) logical subscript too long\n"
> attr(,"class")

Here is a minimal working example per request.

```
set.seed(123)
matrix <- matrix(runif(1000), ncol=10)
boot(matrix,foo,R=50)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is stating `length(coef_nonzero) > ncol(x)`.

Comment: Could you provide a runnable usage example?

Comment: @Oliver I figured that much, but don't quite understand how that's possible if `coef_nonzero` comes from the nonzero coefficients from `glmnet`.

Comment: @jay.sf I've edited the above with an example, however, that won't get an error. I think the error comes with a complex dataset which I can't reproduce myself

Comment: I would suggest debugging your code with such an example. Without a reproducible example it is extremely difficult to come with suggested edits. If this is new to you [data-flair](https://data-flair.training/blogs/debugging-in-r-programming/) has a visual guide for debugging R code. :-)

Comment: @AW27 Basically wrap `tryCatch` around the code that you suspect to fail and provide an alternative output it the argument, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43380987/6574038

Comment: @Oliver thanks, I'll keep trying to debug. I've used the function in `debug` and have had a hard time actually reproducing the error myself. It seems my function works outside of a `for loop` or `lapply` but fails only sometimes in a loop and on different data sets each time.

Comment: @jay.sf the error occurs when I try to subset the matrix `x[,coef_nonzero, drop = FALSE])`, is it possible to skip the `lm` call and return the original `coef` result if this error occurs?

Comment: `cols <- try(x[, coef != 0, dop = FALSE]); if(inherits(cols, 'try-error'))return(coef)` would return the coefficients when an error occurs. Alternatively you could execute `browser()` (instead of returning coef) if you want to start the debugger when the error occurs.

Comment: @Oliver thanks for that, how would I incorporate it into the above function so that if the error doesn't occur, I can continue with performing OLS (assuming there are more than `0` nonzero coefficients)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
foo <- function(data, index) {
  # index is the bootstrap sample index
  x <- data[index, -1]
  y <- data[index, 1]
  ridge <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0)
  ## The intercept estimate should be dropped.
  weights <- as.numeric(coef(ridge, s = ridge$lambda.min))[-1]
  # alpha=1, lasso
  alasso <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1,
                      penalty.factor = 1 / abs(weights))
  # Select nonzero coefficients
  coef <- as.vector(coef(alasso, s = alasso$lambda.min, 
                         exact = TRUE, x = x, y = y,
                         penalty.factor = 1 / abs(weights)))[-1]
  coef_nonzero <- coef != 0
  new_x <- tryCatch(x[, coef_nonzero, drop = FALSE], 
                    error=function(e) NA)
  if (!any(is.na(new_x))) {
    ls.obj <- lm(y ~ new_x)
    ls_coef <- (ls.obj$coefficients)[-1]
    coef[coef_nonzero] <- ls_coef
  }
  return(coef)
}
```

The problem is that we have no case when it fails so far.

Comment: what does `NA` do here? wouldn't it be `if (any(is.na(new_x))) { ls_coef <- coef}; else{ls.obj <- lm(y ~ new_x);ls_coef <- (ls.obj$coefficients)[-1];coef[coef_nonzero] <- ls_coef}`?

Comment: @AW27 `tryCatch` throws `NA` if subsetting of the matrix fails with an error. If we have no `NA`, `lm` code is evaluated, else unchanged `coef` are returned (sorry forgot the `!` before my edit).

Comment: So far this seems to have fixed my issue temporarily, I'm going to try it on a more significant number of bootstraps and hopefully will be able to get results. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AW27 You're welcome. Please inform me, when you identify a concrete case that reproduces a fail so I could take a closer look on that.

Comment: I've encountered the error `Error in t[r, ] <- res[[r]] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Calls: <Anonymous> -> .f -> do.call -> <Anonymous>` when running with `purrr::map` which I believe corresponds to this error. I've edited the function to show you what I have updated and hoping it works

Comment: @AW27 Don't know where you use `purrr::map`, you could try with base `Map`.

Comment: Sorry, I call `purrr::map` since I am running my method on a list of data frames. This function I use contains the above, which is where the error is coming from, I'm going to try `lapply` instead of `purrr::map`